How to go about moving my webserver data onto a (tmpfs) RAM disk? (experiment)
For How to go about moving my webserver data onto a (tmpfs) RAM disk? (experiment), I formulated some ideas, notes, and stuff around. Need to hear if my whole idea is sound and solid, and that such experiment is doable.

Automate the creation of a sufficiently large (tmpfs) RAM disk at boot time.

With the same script, copy the www data , adjust ownership, just about everything.

Logs would stay on my NVMe SSD of type PCIe 3.0 x4:
# nvme list
Node                  SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
--------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1          < SN REDACTED >      Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB             1         360.10  GB /   2.00  TB    512   B +  0 B   2B2QEXM7


The laptop has 32 GB RAM (DDR4 2400 MHz, dual-channel), and I feel it gets unused.

The laptop has a functional battery for a few minutes, but still.

The laptop is plugged into an older UPS, I might need to change the battery (note for me).

My uplink is (almost) 100 Mbits/s. https://www.speedtest.net/result/16116969035

I rarely reboot this laptop, it is 7th-gen Intel-based, and has AES-NI instruction set.

I do about weekly a snapshot with Timeshift-GTK app. Monthly then full clones of both SSDs.

The OS is Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon 64-bit based on Ubuntu 22.04. Current kernel is of version 6.5.0-27.



That is about my notes of this experiment, an interesting one, if you ask me.
I believe the only harder part for me would be writing that shell script for automating it. At the same time interesting it could be. Don't know where to start and what not to forget on. Thanks for all and any tips.

Never tried this, but as a general approach I would try to do the following: creating an image of /var/www-data and mounting it to a tmpfs on startup (maybe recreating the image on shutdown if you need to keep changes done to the tmpfs), then symlinking www-data to the tmpfs, assuming that won't break whatever webserver you're running (the other option being setup the webserver to read from the tmpfs)

The question which comes to mind is "Why?" Is this for self education? Do you hope for some performance gain?

@icarus The perf gain will be minimal I suppose. It is purely self-education experiment of mine.

@kos Thank you for your comment.

Self education is an excellent reason for doing something.


that such experiment is doable.

yes, that sounds trivial. Adressing the things you mention you need to do:

Automate the creation of a sufficiently large (tmpfs) RAM disk at boot time.

That can be done as an entry in /etc/fstab, for example,
tmpfs /var/www/ramdisk tmpfs noauto,size=4g

sets up a 4GB (maximum, don't know why you'd want to specify that, but you asked for it) ramdisk. Tmpfs always only uses the RAM needed to store the files in it, and you have a defined size. Anyways, your choice!
noauto is optional, but since we only need the ramdisk to start the web server, we can wait setting up the ram disk until then – a sensible init system will understand dependencies between mounts and boot units if told about it, and start "in the most convenient order". In other words, lets not bog down early boot by setting up a RAM disk that we'll only need in late boot.

With the same script, copy the www data , adjust ownership, just about everything.

Sure, you can have a script that you execute at boot that does that; no need to be complicated about it, a cp -ar /var/www/disk/* /var/www/ramdisk/ would do. (assuming you set up things with the right permissions in your source). Alternatively, you could unpack a tar or a squashfs archive into your target. Many things preserve ownerships and permissions on linux!
You'd want your "copy over data script" to be part of your boot system such that it always runs before the web server starts. In systemd, that's especially easy, you'll want to place a "setup-ramdisk.service" file in /etc/systemd/system/, and put something like this into it,
[Unit]
Description=Set up contents of RAM disk

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# We're going for the "extract from compressed archive" approach here,
# going for `cp -ar` would be just as valid
ExecStart=unsquashfs -d /var/www/ramdisk /var/www/disk/archive.squash

# Tell the system we need that ramdisk mount
RequiresMountsFor=/var/www/ramdisk

# Make sure that if started at the same time as a web server,
# we need to be done before the web server is started
Before=nginx.service httpd.service apache2.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

So, that's rather easy; systemctl enable --now setup-ramdisk to enable it (for future boots) and run it right now. You could also modify your web server's .service file (probably in /usr/lib/systemd/system/) to list Wants=setup-ramdisk.service and After=setup-ramdisk.service
However,

idea is sound and solid

No. For two reasons:

My uplink is (almost) 100 Mbits/s.

cute. Your SSD is much faster than that, random access times should be lower than jitter in TCP connection establishment, and you have plenty RAM for caching SSD access: Even on the first request to a file, the party requesting the file won't be able to notice the difference between reading from RAM disk or directly from SSD, and as long as you don't use the RAM for something else, that file is going to stay cached in the in-RAM buffers of Linux, anyways. Your RAM disk achieves nothing, aside from keeping RAM occupied for data that you might not even need.
So, I don't see any sense in this experiment. Your bottleneck is clearly your network, not your storage. And even if that wasn't the case, you have plenty of RAM; so file system and block device buffering will make the second time a file is accessed as fast as if the file was in RAM disk already, unless of course some other software needed the RAM and the file was expelled from these buffers to get free RAM. But in that case, it would be worse if your server had the files in a RAM disk: that RAM demand would then either fail (and something would crash) or something would get killed by the out-of-memory killer (so, your system would become unreliable), or that RAM request would push other software and its in-RAM data into swap space – with catastrophic effects for performance, especially if that affects the web server – and it would quite possibly affect the web server, as that would not have served the file in quite some time for it to be considered for expulsion.
So, all in all:

Unnecessary, because storage is not your bottleneck
Unnecessary, because RAM caching is a feature that you get for free on Linux. Potentially even harmful in a situation where anything else actually needs much RAM.


Thank you for your answer. I think I won't go for this experiment then. Thanks again
